# Stretch an element even though its child element is floated

Tags: html, css-float

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background:red;">
 <div id="child" style="height:500px;float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make `#wrapper` stretch with the height of `#child`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to clear the float via clear:both, so that the wrapper box knows the end.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background:red;">
 <div id="child" style="height:500px;float:left;"></div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a better way to do a clearfix: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 1):

Add a clearfix class to the parent div. Here is the CSS: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/hqUHu/)

```
.cf { zoom: 1; }
.cf:before, .cf:after { content: ""; display: table; }         
.cf:after { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

give the parent a height: 0px auto;
the initial height in px is what you  want it to start at and auto  will allow this to adjust based on the height of its children

Comment: but remember you should also give it a width(the parent) if you give it a set width then anything that can't properly float on that side will break to the next line this will also increase the height as well